# Is it possible to link menu <li> to widgetID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a lyrics blog in blogger. I know that its imposible to create directory file in blogger. So i have an idea. I can list singer's name using LABEL widget, but is it possible to link menu `<li>` to widget???
And if its posible, we can hide and show those widget wherever we want, right?

so i mean like this...

```
<li><a href='WidgetLabelA'>A</a></li>
<li><a href='WidgetLabelB'>B</a></li>
<li><a href='WidgetLabelC'>C</a></li>
```

Comment: what is a `"menu <li>"` and a `LABEL widget` - perhaps there's some tag you've missed, because in the context of javascript, jquery and html I have no idea what those things are

Comment: Your question is not clear, please provide more information, for instance what do you mean by widget? class, id, element?

Comment: i mean like this sir.. T_T..
http://prntscr.com/7x4g73

Comment: dont laughing me sir... T_T i dunno anything about programming.. i just learn by myslef to edit a template.. T_T